# Variance of a Discrete Random Variable

Tags: random-variables

Can someone help me wrap my mind around this:

When calculating the variance of a sample, we divide the squared distance of each data point from the mean by the sample size - 1. But how come we don't need to divide the sum by anything when we are calculating the variance of a discrete random variable?

Comment: There is an essential difference between  the variance of a *sample* (it is a random variable) and the variance of a *random variable* (it is a real number, if it exists). In the second case there is no (comparable) sum.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, the first case you mention is actually the way you *estimate* the variance of a set of $n$ indipendent, identically distributed random variables. Division by $n-1$ is then necessary so that the *random variable* you obtain in this way, has expected value equal to the variance you want to estimate.